# How to uninstall an app on Splunk from CLI?

Tags: splunk

Can someone please guide how to uninstall an app from Splunk using CLI?

I know how to delete the app from the Splunk Etc folder...need guidance using CLI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A quick search turns up several pointers, e.g. [Manage app and add-on objects – from docs.splunk.com](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Admin/Managingappobjects). It's best you clarify in which way existing solutions and documentation doesn't help you. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you "know how to delete the app from the Splunk Etc folder", you know how to "uninstall an app on Splunk from CLI"

Answer (score 1):

`rm -r /opt/splunk/etc/apps/myapp; splunk restart` uses the CLI, but perhaps you want to use a Splunk command.  If so, try `splunk remove app myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is quite easy.

Open a terminal window (Linux or Mac) or command prompt (Windows) on your Splunk Enterprise server.
Run the following command to stop Splunk Enterprise: /bin/splunk stop.

Run the following command to remove the Code42 Insider Threat app for Splunk: ...
Restart Splunk.

source : https://uninstallguide.com/how-to-uninstall-splunk-app.html